# What does "resolve symlink" mean?

Tags: shell, directory, symlink, cd-command, ln

Im confused about this bash option:

> -P
>
> If set, do not **resolve** symbolic links when performing commands such as cd which change the current directory. The physical directory
> is used instead. By default, Bash follows the logical chain of
> directories when performing commands which change the current
> directory.
>
> ```
> For example, if /usr/sys is a symbolic link to /usr/local/sys then:
>
> $ cd /usr/sys; echo $PWD
> /usr/sys
> $ cd ..; pwd
> /usr
>
> If set -P is on, then:
>
> $ cd /usr/sys; echo $PWD
> /usr/local/sys
> $ cd ..; pwd
> /usr/local
> ```

I thought resolve means to follow? e.g /usr/sys points at /usr/local/sys, so it would get resolved to /usr/local/sys.
But the example above says that when `set -P` is on, /usr/sys becomes /usr/local/says? Even though it says if its on it shouldnt resolve symbolic links

Comment: The question is: who is doing the resolving? With the default behaviour, bash resolves the symlink and then pretends that you're in `/usr/sys` instead of in `/usr/local/sys`. With `set -P`, bash doesn't do anything by itself and lets the underlying system behaviour show (which is also to resolve the symlink, but now it's impossible to be in `/usr/sys`).

Answer (score 0):

```
vm1:/home/millerp > ln -s /var/log ./log
vm1:/home/millerp > set -P
vm1:/home/millerp > cd log
vm1:/var/log > cd
vm1:/home/millerp > set +P
vm1:/home/millerp > cd log
vm1:/home/millerp/log >
```

With -P, the cwd is not resolved (converted) to the link, it is shown as the actual (physical) path. With +P, the cwd is resolved to the symlink path.

As muru points out, the question is 'resovlved for whom?'